# without defining public property is accessible using $this in php OOP

Tags: php, oop, php-7

i'm trying to do something like this:

```
<?php
class Circle{
    //public $radious=1;
    function SetRadius($param)
    {
        $this->radious=$param;
    }
    function AreaOfCircle(){
        return $this->radious * $this->radious * M_PI;
    }
}
$obj=new Circle();
$obj->SetRadius(5);
echo $obj->AreaOfCircle(); //78.539816339745
?>
```

i have defined one property in class level :
but when i comment this (radius) property,the program is working  fine. but **as per the oop concept** **it should return error : "undefined property"**. but i got it is working well without defining property. ***can anyone help me why it is working ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**i got the concept.**

PHP classes are not quite the same as in other languages, where member variables need to be specified as part of the class declaration. PHP class members can be created at any time.